# Why the error "Generic type 'Record' requires 2 type argument(s). ts(2314)" using this form of typing?

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to use this type but I can't:

```
type ROLES = "one" | "two"

type Users = {
    name: Record<[key in ROLES]?, User[]>;
};
```

because it throws with:

```
Generic type 'Record' requires 2 type argument(s). ts(2314)
```

Why?

Comment: I am getting a different error. Can you provide a [Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play) where the error can be seen? You probably want to this `name: Partial<Record<ROLES, User[]>>`

Comment: the error message says it all. you have to define two generics, so if you want the key to be a key of roles then you need to remove the `?` and use `Record<ROLES, User[]>`. if you want optional entries you can use `Partial<Record<ROLES, User[]>>`.

Comment: 1st arg for Record must resolve into string, so what are you trying to achieve.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error message says it all. you have to define two generics, so if you want the key to be a key of `ROLES` then you need to remove the `?` and use `Record<ROLES, User[]>`. if you want optional entries you can use `Partial<Record<ROLES, User[]>>`.